# Problem with setting ConnectorGroupId with Set-AzureADApplicationProxyApplication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

My code is below:

```
$aadapConnectorGroups=Get-AzureADApplicationProxyConnectorGroup -Top 100000 


foreach ($item in $aadapConnectorGroups)
 {
    
   If ($item.ConnectorGroupType -eq "applicationProxy" -And $item.Name -eq $ConnectorGroupIdName)
    {
        
         New-AzureADApplicationProxyApplication `
        -DisplayName  $ApplicationName `
        -ExternalUrl $ExternalUrl `
        -InternalUrl $InternalUrl `
        -IsHttpOnlyCookieEnabled $isHttpOnlyCookieEnabled `
        -ApplicationServerTimeout $applicationServerTimeout `
        -IsPersistentCookieEnabled $isPersistentCookieEnabled `
        -ConnectorGroupId $item.ObjectID             
        
    }

 }
```

I am having below error while i try to set the `ConnectorGroupId` with `Set-AzureADApplicationProxyApplication`.

```
Error occurred while executing SetApplicationProxyApplication Code:
Request_ResourceNotFound Message: Resource
'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx' does not exist or one of its queried
reference-property objects are not present.
```

I get the same error while i create a  create new Azure AD Application Proxy Application with `New-AzureADApplicationProxyApplication`.

When i try the default **ConnectorGroupId**, it works perfectly well. So i guess that the problem is with the **ConnectorGroup** that i have recently created. However, on the portal, i see my new **ConnectorGroup** created and works well.

With `Get-AzureADApplicationProxyConnectorGroup` command, i can see my new **ConnectorGroup** also.

I can assign it to a AzureADApplicationProxyApplication **from the portal**. So logically, it should be working from the cli as well.

Do you have any idea why i have this error?

EDIT:
I have also tried the below command:

```
 Set-AzureADApplicationProxyApplication -ObjectId $item2.ObjectID
 -ConnectorGroupId $item.ObjectID -Verbose
```

Although, it returned success message, it didn't change the ConnectorGroupId of the application. I have verified from the portal and cli.

Answer (score 1):

```
Error occurred while executing SetApplicationProxyApplication Code:
Request_ResourceNotFound Message: Resource
'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx' does not exist or one of its queried
reference-property objects are not present.
```

This error means the `-ObjectId` doesn't exist, not the `-ConnectorGroupId`.

And when you create a new Azure AD Application Proxy Application with `New-AzureADApplicationProxyApplication`, you don't need to specify the `-ObjectId`, so I'm not sure why you get this error.

You need to specify the correct object id:

```
New-AzureADApplicationProxyApplication -DisplayName "Finance Tracker10" -ExternalUrl $externalUrl -InternalUrl $internalUrl -ConnectorGroupId $connectorGroupId

$app = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Finance Tracker10'"

Set-AzureADApplicationProxyApplication -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -ConnectorGroupId $newConnectorGroupId -ExternalUrl $newExternalUrl -InternalUrl $newInternalUrl1
```

Comment: On Set-AzureADApplicationProxyApplication command, why you specified new ExternalUrl and InternalUrl? Normally, they are optional. Is it necessary to set the ConnectorGroupId?

Comment: I have added the code which creates the Application.

Comment: I understood my error. I am using -ConnectorGroupId $item.ObjectID . But ConnectorGroupId doesn't have ObjectID property but Id. So when i changed it, the issue is fixed.

Comment: @MoonHorse I was prompted ExternalUrl and InternalUrl are required, so I set the new ones.

Comment: @MoonHorse Glad to know that. You can post an answer:)